# How can I update a user's profile information in Weavy?

Tags: weavy

I recently integrated the Weavy chat sdk in my react application and want to update a particular profile's information. I searched the weavy documentation but couldn't get a proper answer.

I tried updating it frrom the Weavy dashboard but failed to do so as there was nothing specific about it. The dashboard is only showing the number of monthly active user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update user profile information with the Web API. Specifically the [update user](https://www.weavy.com/docs/reference/api-reference/users#update-user) and/or [sync user](https://www.weavy.com/docs/reference/api-reference/users#sync-user) api endpoints.